# Pegar posição do mouse em máquinas virtuais

Tags: delphi, posição-do-cursor

Estou tendo um problema em pegar a posição do mouse em uma máquina virtual.

Tenho um programa de macro em uma máquina virtual que executa uma série de ações em loop, mas pode acontecer da ação travar e o único modo de detectar isso é com o movimento do mouse. Fiz um pequeno sistema em Delphi que captura a posição do mouse e caso ele permaneça mais de 5 minutos no mesmo lugar eu recebo um e-mail, mas quando eu me desconecto da máquina virtual e deixo a macro executando nela, meu sistema em Delphi para de capturar a posição.

Alguém sabe um método para resolver isso? Pode ser em qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Já pensou em, ao invés de capturar a posição do mouse, deixar um sinal em algum lugar? Ou incrementar um contador a cada iteração do seu laço... Se você fizer isso com um serviço, você pode acessar o serviço remotamente para ver verificar se sua aplicação está ativa.

Comment: O problema é que cada loop da macro pode ter um tempo indefinido, um loop pode ter tempo de 5 minutos até 20, tudo depende do caso em especial.

Comment: Você pode incrementar um contador no serviço e em um programa cliente fazer uma requisição a cada cinco minutos (ou outro intervalo arbitrário). Pense fora da caixa ;)

Comment: Por que não abre uma `thread` nesse mesmo programa da macro e verifica o estado do mouse (ou dele mesmo) através dessa `thread`?

Comment: @felipe.avelar não é possivel modificar a macro, é um sistema chamado Automate, creio que fazer o sistema capturar a posição e enviar para o meu sistema é valido, vlw.

Comment: Se o usuário sair do pc por 5 minutos como fica esta detecção?

Comment: @Bacco Não fico conectado a vm, por isso gostaria de desenvolver um sistema que identifique quando a macro está parada, mas tem que ser algo que não envolva diretamente o funcionamento da macro, por isso um programa externo que captura o mouse, mas pelo que vi o sistema não considera que a macro esteja movimentando o mouse.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "conectado à VM"? Qual programa de virtualização e sistema operacional hóspede você usa? Digo qual é a versão de Windows virtualizada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagino que você esteja usando a API do windows para recuperar a posição do cursor, mas esta função deva parar de funcionar quando você desconecta, final não há um "monitor" para que seja possível dizer a posição atual.

Sem saber a tecnologia usada na macro, também é complicado fazer afirmações, mas imagino que ela use as APIs do windows para clicar em botões, digitar texto, etc.

Bem, essa macro deve ter um mecanismo, em cada evento, para determinar se ela pode ou não continuar com as ações.

Enfim, uma solução neste caso, é fazer com que cada vez que a macro esteja aguardando o próximo passo do loop, ela conte o tempo e, em caso de falha, execute o programa que envia o e-mail.

Uma outra abordagem, caso você esteja monitorando um programa específico, seria monitorar outro elemento que não o mouse. Se a macro passa por várias telas, você poderia verificar o título da janela atual com a API do windows. Outra possibilidade seria capturar a imagem da janela em intervalos regulares e verificar se alguma coisa mudou.

Em última instância, você pode replicar a mesmo lógica que a macro usa para aguardar o sistema para verificar se ela está ou não aguardando indefinidamente.

Porém, se a macro é "burra" no sentido de que ela não tem verificações, apenas vai atuando em intervalos de tempo definidos, você pode pensar em outra solução.

Existe uma ferramenta chamada [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) que permite fazer automação usando imagens. Por exemplo, você captura a imagem de um botão e então monta um script para clicar nesse botão através da imagem. O sikuli vai procurar a imagem do botão na tela e pode aguardar um tempo até que esse botão apareça. Se o botão esperado não aparecer, então você pode capturar o erro. Implementações do Sikuli podem ser feitas em java ou Python.

---

**Atualização**

Fiz uma pesquisa sobre as APIs relacionadas à posição do cursor do mouse. A posição do mouse geralmente é dada em relação ao monitor atual, já que o Windows suporte múltiplas telas. Então quando você desconecta todos os monitores o cursor pode ser desabilitado.

Suponho que atualmente você esteja usando o [`GetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28VS.85%29.aspx). Se for isso, tente verificar o [`GetCursorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), pois ele retorna informações úteis sobre o estado do cursor e também sobre sua posição.

Entretanto, parece que essa informação não é acessível por decisão de projeto mesmo. Veja [este link](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/752887-getcursorpos-not-working-if-desktop-locked), que diz mais ou menos isso:

> Você não pode obter essa informação com o desktop bloqueado. Enquanto ele está bloqueado, o subsistema de segurança entre toma conta e seu desktop está fora dos limites.

Comment: Luiz, o problema é que, quando não estou conectado é como se o mouse não se movimentação, parece que o programa que captura a posição não considera que a macro está mexendo o mouse.

Comment: @MDomingues O programa que você fez roda dentro ou fora da máquina virtual?

Comment: Ele roda dentro da maquina, capturando a posição atual do mouse, caso o mouse permaneça mais que 5 minutos parado ele envia um e-mail para mim, avisando que a macro está parada.

Comment: @MDomingues Certo, não havia me atentado a esse detalhe. Qual é a tecnologia de virtualização que você usa?

Comment: As maquinas virtuais são montadas dentro de um servidor linux, não tenho mais detalhes sobre, mas cada vm utiliza um sistema Windows XP, para melhor compatibilidade com a macro. Me conecto as vm's utilizando o programa "Remote Desktop Connection Mananger", mas após iniciar a macro me desconecto.

Comment: @MDomingues Ajustei a resposta para refletir minhas sugestões atuais.

Comment: Muito obrigado, estou lendo e assim que que possível posto o desfecho.

Comment: @MDomingues Fiz mais algumas pesquisas e adicionei uma atualização na resposta. Nada muito animador, entretanto.